# URL Rewriting from .htaccess with Symfony Routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have some trouble RewritingUrl with Symfony (2.8)
My objective is to redirect some URL **without** having them changing in the browser bar.

I need this so the URL may have a custom, human-readable form, and being shareable.

The URL is also used in a Form thus why the data are sent in the `?param=data` shape

Homewever, Symfony internal routing seems to not quite work with it ( or maybe have  I overlooked some stuff but I've seeking up and down all day for this without finding the right answer )

Without the framework, in a .htaccess 
If a user went to

```
www.website.com/search/London/15
```

I would redirect them to

```
www.website.com/searchEngine?search_action[city]=London&search_action[radius]=15
```

Without changing the browser URL so searchEngine nevers shows up , with a simple RewriteRule

```
 RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)$ /searchEngine?search_action[city]=$1&search_action[radius]=$2 [L]
```

But once I  try to use this same rule with Symfony ( in the .htaccess in the **/web** forlder, right ?),

www.website.com/search/London/15 land on a Symfony 404 Error Page

My guess is that Symfony tries to look for an internal /Search route, which does not exist as the URL is intended to silently redirect to SearchEngin through the .htaccess

SearchEngine route **does** exist and `www.website.com/SearchEngine?search_action[city]=London&search_action[radius]=15` works very fine

So far, .htaccess and Symfony works together if I add the R flag to the RewriteRule

```
 RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)$ /searchEngine?search_action[city]=$1&search_action[radius]=$2 [R,L]
```

But that's because the URL changes in the  browser as it is redirected to SearchEngine.

Is there a way so that Symfony knows that `/search/London/15` leads to `SearchEngine?search_action[city]=London&search_action[radius]=15`, and works without the Url changing ?

Anyone have an idea as to what I should tweak for that ?

## Routing

Quite really basic , a single Route just for that URL readable feature and Search,  nothing too fancy.

### routing.yml

```
research_action:
path:     /SearchEngine
defaults: { _controller: "MySearchBundle:Search:search" }
```

### SearchController:searchAction

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    /*
       expect search_action[city]=London and search_action[radius]=15
    */
    $form = $this->createForm('MySearchBundle\Form\Type\SearchType',null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
         //Get here without problem when from SearchEngine?search_action[city]=London&search_action[radius]=15
           /* 
               This is where Zhuli do the thing
             */

    }
  return $this->render('SomeDefaultPage.html.twig');
}
```

### .htaccess

```
...
//Basic Symfony Routing stuff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
#Doesn't work without that R tag
RewriteRule search/(.*)/(.*)$ /SearchEngine?search_action[city]=$1&search_action[radius]=$2 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
.....
```

Comment: Show your Symfony route configuration, and probably your controller too. That will make it easier to see where you've gone wrong. You can configured multiple routes for a single controller action so maybe that will help..

Comment: Added them, sorry took a bit of time

Comment: @naththedeveloper I see the idea but to make the Form work behind it, Symfony needs to receive `/SearchEngine?search_action[city]=Prague&search_action[radius]=15` and unless I decide to tweak the way the Form process the request, I don't think adding multiple route could work.

Comment: Have you tried putting your custom rules before the symfony ones in htaccess? That should stop it from interfering...

Comment: @Bananaapple ? I haven't tried but what Symfony Rule could interfere ?

Comment: @Bananaapple  I have tried now, putted the rule juste after the `RewriteEngine On` , and still it does not work without the R flag. 
Symfony tries to handle `/Search/Otawa/25` as the `/Search` route and towards a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found something 
which is quite longer than just a rule in `.htaccess`, but I could not find another workaround.

I created a new Route  which will **forward** the `/search/London/15` query toward the SearchEngine

```
forward_action:
path:     /search/{city}/{radius}
defaults: { _controller: "MySearchBundle:Search:searchForward" }
```

### Controller

In the Controller Action I retrieve the URL Attribute (city and radius ) that I pass to the Request:ParameterBag; which I then forward to the SearchEngineAction

```
  public function searchForwardAction(Request $request,$city,$radius)
  {
        //Putting the attribute in an array
        $query['city']=$city;
        $query['radius']=$radius;
        /*
           Which I pass to the request as a parameter
           The forward will treat this like a Get Query
           ?search_action[city]=$city&search_action[radius]=$radius
         */
        $request->query->set('search_action',$query);
        //Forwarding !
        return $this->forward('MySearchBundle:Search:search',  array('request' => $request));
}
```

Since I use `forward()` the URL on the browser stays like `/Search/Kyoto/25`
but return the result of `/SearchEngine?search_action[city]=Kyoto&search_action[radius]=25`

It works quite fine but the amount of code and work for just this URL rewriting becomes quite heavy if one compares it to normally a **single** rule in an .htaccess ( which still does not work properly)

And I will have to modify where the Search Form direct to

I doubt it to be THE best solution since it is quite ..complicated for a such simple task.

Anyone got better ?